# reduce the expression of a probability formula

Tags: probability

So consider the following experiment: We have 2by2 positive definite matrices $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ and two vectors $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$ in $\mathbf{R}^2$. 
We toss a coin, if the coin lands in head we let the random variable $Y$ be $1$. If the coin land in tail we let the random variable $Y$ be $0$. If the coins landed in head, we choose a point $X=x$ in $R^2$ with the distribution $P(X=x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{det(\Sigma_1)}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\sigma_1)^{T} \Sigma_1^{-1}(x-\sigma_1)}$. If the coin landed tail, we choose a point in $\mathbf{R}^2$ using the following distribution : $P(X=x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{det(\Sigma_2)}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\sigma_2)^{T} \Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\sigma_2)}$. Now what is the probability that the coin landed tail given that we pick the point $x$?

So the probability is $P(Y=0|X=x)=\frac{P(X=x|Y=0)P(Y=0)}{P(X=x|Y=0)P(Y=0)+P(X=x|Y=1)P(Y=1)}$. So the answer hase three exponent terms, I'm wondering if it is possible to reduce the expression to one exponent term?

Comment: $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ are $4 \times 4$ matrices, not $2 \times 2$?

Comment: Sorry yes , I corrected it

Comment: There's an obvious simplification because $P(Y=0) = P(Y = 1)$, but I doubt the formula simplifies any further except for special values of $\Sigma_i$ and $\sigma_i$.